# IE6/7 CSS Class Overriding

Tags: html, css

I have a css file like:

```
#SomeTable.hideAll td { display: none; }
#SomeTable.showXYZ .show { display: block }
```

When I add the class show to a td, the display overrides to block in chrome, FF, and IE8. But in IE6/7, the display stays none like it is not being overridden. Is there something odd you have to do in old IE's to do a css override like this? I suspect it has something to do with it either not being possible, or I just don't understand rules for determining an override.

EDIT: even if the css rules look like

```
.hide { display: none; }
#SomeTable.showXYZ td { display: block }
```

The css still does not get updated. This can't be a specificity thing, but must be an IE6/7 bug.

Comment: This is `td` specific. But didn't you ask a very similar question two days ago?

Comment: Elaborate on the td specific thing. Yes, I asked a question about css the other day, but I don't see how that relates.

Comment: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/ CSS specificity can be a bit confusing. It sounds like an IE6/IE7 CSS specificity bug, since .show should be overriding td since classes are more specific than simple elements. Hopefully polarblau's answer will get you there.

Comment: IE6 (and IE7 in quirks mode) doesn't support combined ID and class selectors such as `#SomeTable.hideAll`.

Comment: interesting, although this is happening in IE7 in standards mode too

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this yet? —

```
#SomeTable.hideAll td { display: none; }
#SomeTable.showXYZ td.show { display: block; }
```

Comment: My answer remains the same and is identical with Pekka's comment: "td" has a higher specificity than the class name. User "td.show" instead. I'll update my answer to match your class names.

Comment: Do you have an example that you could put up somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The `<td>` element and other table-related elements should not be set to `display:block` or `display:inline`. They have their own specific table-relevant display types, which should be used instead.

eg:

```
table.mytable {dislpay:table;}
td.mycell {display:table-cell;}
```

In some browsers, `display:block;` may also work, but this is not correct, and will definitely cause problems in other browsers. The above display types are the correct ones.

However there are some inconsistencies in support for these display types between different browsers, notably older versions of IE.

The best option, which will be compatible for all browsers, is simply to specify nothing where you want it to be shown -- ie

```
#SomeTable.hideAll .hide { display: none; }
#SomeTable.showXYZ .show {  } /* nothing here */
```

Doing this, when you specify the class as `show`, it will pick up the default display type for the element type. This works even if you switch between `hide` and `show` and back again.